# Finding quartiles without doubles

Tags: c, algorithm, statistics

I am using the following code (and works as expected) for find Q1, Q2 and Q3, but I'm not able to write `set_qrt()` using only `int`'s and `%` for find the position

for `1.0, 2.0, 3.0` quartiles must be **Q1 = 1.5 ; Q2 = 2.0 ; Q3 = 2.5**

for `1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0` quartiles must be **Q1 = 2.0 ; Q2 = 3.5 ; Q3 = 5.0**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    double qrt[3];
    double *value;
    int count;
} t_data;

static void set_qrt(t_data *data, int qrt)
{
    int n, e;
    double d; /* I want to avoid that */

    d = qrt * data->count * 0.25 + 0.5;
    n = (int)d;
    e = n != d;
    data->qrt[qrt - 1] = data->value[n - 1];
    if (e) {
        data->qrt[qrt - 1] += data->value[n];
        data->qrt[qrt - 1] *= 0.5;
    }
}

static void set_qrts(t_data *data)
{
    set_qrt(data, 2);
    if (data->count > 1) {
        set_qrt(data, 1);
        set_qrt(data, 3);
    } else {
        data->qrt[0] = 0.0;
        data->qrt[2] = 0.0;
    }
}

static int comp(const void *pa, const void *pb)
{
    const double a = *(const double *)pa;
    const double b = *(const double *)pb;

    return (a > b) ? 1 : (a < b) ? -1 : 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    double values[] = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0};
    t_data data;

    data.value = values;
    data.count = (int)(sizeof(values) / sizeof(double));
    qsort(data.value, data.count, sizeof(double), comp);
    set_qrts(&data);
    printf("Q1 = %.1f\nQ2 = %.1f\nQ3 = %.1f\n", data.qrt[0], data.qrt[1], data.qrt[2]);
}
```

Comment: Your data values here are floats. You're kind of stuck with using floats for statistics as long as that's the case. If they are in fact all integers, then to accurately represent quartiles you'll have to calculate them *4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure of what you want, but if you want to change theses two lines :

```
d = qrt * data->count * 0.25 + 0.5;
n = (int)d;
```

and not using d to directly get the integer value, you just have to do :

```
n = (qrt * data->count +2)/4;
```

and to check if this is the real number of just a truncature :

```
e = ((qrt * data->count +2) % 4) != 0;
```

this way, you'll know if n is a decimal, and you'll have it's value

Comment: Thank you, but I give `Q1 = 1.0 ; Q2 = 2.5 ; Q3 = 2.0` for `1.0, 2.0, 3.0`

Comment: Actually, I made a mistake in my algorithm. This is corrected now, the == should have been a !=

Comment: if ((qrt * data->count * 0.25) - 0.5) is integer we choose the (position - 1) else we choose the (((position - 1) + position) / 2)

Comment: Yeah, i figured it out. This code should work now with my modification

Comment: Why +2 (as you can see maths are not my forte)

Comment: +0.5 == +2/4 and 0.25 == 1/4. That's how you can get rid of double numbers ^^